# Swipe down for search

Tags: android, swipe

Im trying change swipe-for-refresh to swipe-for-search like on this picture. How I can do this?
[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement **MotionEvent** that can be you can find swip down on any view as like listview or imageview. See below code how to do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
// This example shows an Activity, but you would use the same approach if
 // you were subclassing a View.
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

switch(action) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                "of current screen element");
        return true;      
    default : 
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}      
}
```